# Create a shortcut to a subsection of ubuntu settings (example: network, bluetooth, wifi)

Tags: shortcut-keys, network-manager, gui, shortcuts

[image]

Is there a way to create a icon shortcut that automatically opens the Network section in the ubuntu Settings?

Or is there a way to open the Network Manager GUI itself alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open Network Connections (from Network Manager) from command-line as `nm-connection-editor`.

Also you can open some applets of GNOME Control Center from command-line. If you open terminal, write `gnome-control-center` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> you will get the following list of subcommands:

```
$ gnome-control-center 
background        mouse             region            user-accounts
bluetooth         network           removable-media   --verbose
color             notifications     search            --version
datetime          online-accounts   sharing           wacom
default-apps      --overview        sound             wifi
display           power             thunderbolt       
info-overview     printers          ubuntu            
keyboard          privacy           universal-access
```

So you can create for example these shortcuts:

- `gnome-control-center bluetooth` for Bluetooth
- `gnome-control-center network` for Network (Wired, VPN and Proxy)
- `gnome-control-center wifi` for Wi-Fi networking

and so on.